# Not able to create UI Controls at runtime

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to create a screen on which I have a `Panel`. The main `Panel` has another `Panel` and this `Panel` has a `Grid` which has four `HBoxes`, and each `HBox` finally has a `Button`.

```
  onInit:function(){

        oMainPanel.removeAllContent();
        var oHbox1 = new sap.m.HBox(jQuery.sap.uid());
        var oHbox2 = new sap.m.HBox(jQuery.sap.uid());
        var oHbox3 = new sap.m.HBox(jQuery.sap.uid());
        var oHbox4 = new sap.m.HBox(jQuery.sap.uid());



        var oPanel ;
        var oGrid;
        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
               oGrid = new sap.ui.layout.Grid(jQuery.sap.uid(),{
                hSpacing: 1,
                vSpacing: 1,
                content: [oHbox1,oHbox2,oHbox3,oHbox4]
            });

             oPanel = new sap.m.Panel(jQuery.sap.uid(),{

                headerText: "Some Text",
                expandable: true,
                expanded: true,
                width:"100%",
                content:[oGrid]

            });
            jQuery.sap.delayedCall(100, this, function() {

        });
        oMainPanel.addContent(oPanel);
        }
```

I can see the content in each `HBox`, but only for the last `Panel`. I think these are being overlapped. How can I display the content of all the `HBoxes` in all `Panels`?.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use the same instances of `HBox` as `content` of different `Grids`. You need to create a new instance for each `Panel`.

Try doing something like:

```
 oGrid = new sap.ui.layout.Grid(jQuery.sap.uid(),{
                hSpacing: 1,
                vSpacing: 1,
                content: [new sap.m.HBox(), new sap.m.HBox(), 
                          new sap.m.HBox(), new sap.m.HBox()]
```

or initialize your variables (`oHbox1`, `oHbox2`, etc) inside the loop

Comment: Hello Juan,
First of all, thank you. With your solution, my problem has been solved but only If I don't use the jQuery.sap.delayedCall. Actually I am rendering the charts in my Hbox instead of buttons. So if I don't give the delay I can not render the charts and if I give the delay , charts are being created for last row.

Comment: I solved this problem by using the forEach instead of for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using the forEach instead of for loop.